# Using the ASP.NET ClientServerManager method or property to get name of control

Tags: asp.net

Does the ASP.NET ClientServerManager provide some method or property to return the name of an ASP.NET control in the generated html page that could be used to write the javascript (using RegisterClientScriptBlock) in the code-behind?  The actual generated control names can be quite long and unknown (I am also using master pages).  I would like a generic way to write the javascript text and have the actual names of the controls be added to the javascript string.  I would expect some method that I pass in the name of the control and it returns the actual html control name.  I have searched in the documentation of the ClientServerManager and could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control.ClientID is rendered as html tag ID, so you can use that property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about control names, check out ClientIdMode where you can specify this and make it much simpler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Would this help your issue?

Comment: I am not looking to change the names but just find some way to use them in a generic way.

Comment: If you are referencing from script you may want to make the names simpler. btw.. the link I sent you had the ClientID tag in it if you read it - same as the accepted answer.